# How to reference li inside an if statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying some basic Javasript trying to add a class name to a clicked li item. 
Heres what i have got so far.

```
 //click event to toggle todo
ul.addEventListener('click',  function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    console.log('checked')
    this.classList.add("mystyle");
 }
});
```

instead of  console.log  I  am not  sure how to  access the actual li clicked to then add classname to it. This doesnt seem to reference the li.

Comment: Well, if the condition is passed, e.target refers to the li you need.

Comment: `e.target.classList.add("mystyle")`?

Comment: worked it out. e.target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i did it was like this:

```
//click event to toggle todo
ul.addEventListener('click',  function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
  }
});
```

Toggle  saves having to add an if statement to check that the  class has a name.

Comment: Note, that this works only when the li element contains plain text. If there are one or more elements in the li element, things will get more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar  = '<ul class="linksUnit">';
myVar     += '<li>Link 1';
if (myVar2) { // note != false means true
    // insert a nested unordered list
    myVar += '<ul>';
    myVar += '<li>Link 2</li>';
    myVar += '</ul>';
}
myVar     += '</li>'; 
myVar     += '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you have predefined your list elements, you can loop them and check if they have the class you want to add. If you are generating list elements dynamically you have to use event delegations to add/remove class. Here is an simple example of predefined list elements
[Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/c6psbn3r/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-holder">
 <li>Test</li>
 <li>Test</li>
 <li>Test</li>
 <li>Test</li>
 <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
let listElements = document.querySelectorAll('.list-holder li');

for(let i = 0 ; i < listElements.length; i++) {
    listElements[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {    
    if(!listElements[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      listElements[i].classList.add('active');
    } else {
      listElements[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }); 
}
```

And if you want to keep only one element with active class, here's an updated jsfiddle [Keep active element only one](https://jsfiddle.net/c6psbn3r/1/)